# Call a service from any POD

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I would like how to call a service from any pod inside or outsite the node.

I have 3 nodes with deployment and services. I already have a kube-proxy.

I exec bash on other pod:

```
kubectl exec --namespace=develop myotherdpod-78c6bfd876-6zvh2 -i -t -- /bin/bash
```

And inside my other pod I have tried to exec curl:

```
curl -v http://myservice.develop.svc.cluster.local/user
```

This is my created service:

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "myservice",
    "namespace": "develop",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/develop/services/mydeployment-svc",
    "uid": "1b5fb4ae-ecd1-11e7-8599-02cc6a4bf8be",
    "resourceVersion": "10660278",
    "creationTimestamp": "2017-12-29T19:47:30Z",
    "labels": {
      "app": "mydeployment-deployment"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "name": "http",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 80,
        "targetPort": 8080
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "app": "mydeployment-deployment"
    },
    "clusterIP": "100.99.99.140",
    "type": "ClusterIP",
    "sessionAffinity": "None"
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a definitive answer, but some quick things to check for: Is KubeDNS set up correctly? Can you call the service via its `clusterIP` address, instead of by name? Can you call the individual pods via their Pod IPs?

Comment: Yes, and don't work. I think that my problem is that the other service is in other node. And I cant ping too.

Comment: I recommend you going through https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me that something may be incorrect with the Network Overlay you deployed. First of all, I would double check that the pod can access kube-dns and obtain the proper IP of the service.

```
nslookup myservice.develop.svc.cluster.local
nslookup myservice # If they are in the same namespace it should work as well
```

If you are able to confirm that, then I would also check if services like kube-proxy are working correctly. You can do it by using

```
systemctl status kube-proxy
```

If that does not work I will also check the pods from the Overlay network by executing

```
kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system
```

If they are all ok, I would try using a different network overlay: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/

If that did not work either, I would check if there are firewall rules preventing some communication between the nodes.